# Is there a change on pretty printer in python between GDB 7.7 and 7.11?

Tags: gdb

I am to write a pretty printer in python for my c++ class. Our system has GDB 7.7 while the documentation on [GDB web site](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) is 7.11, I am not sure where to get the documentation for 7.7.

Do you know as far as pretty printer concerns, if there is any change between these 2 versions?

My checking out in another system seems indicates some changes between 7.2 and 7.7 on how to register printer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there have been substantial changes to pretty-printing per se.  However there have been a number of additions to other parts of the Python API between 7.7 and 7.11.

Normally documentation is installed in "info" form on your system when gdb is installed.  Some distros put the documentation into a separate package, so you may need to explicitly install that.

You can also look for the `NEWS` file in the gdb source tree.  It documents most major changes, including changes to the Python API.  You should be able to read all the entries between 7.7 and 7.11 online.

Another option would be to build your own gdb.  Then you can pick what version to use.